# advantages of using sitecore media library vs regular content tree

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

First, let me say that this is not an opinionated question.  There are likely some very tangible and objective reasons why I should use the media library in sitecore rather than placing the items in the content tree.

I am currently working on a solution that likely arrived at storing items in the regular content tree to keep the individual sites separate and query paths easily written for scoping to the correct locations.

That said, if we wanted to make a case for using the media library what objective benefits are there.  Any performance implications, features that you'd miss out on?

Thanks

Comment: funny I'm getting voted to close for opinions, I don't want opinions I want the facts of why this feature was created.  There must be a reason

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the media item through the media-handler that way. You should use the Media Library. Otherwise you'll miss caching, cropping and all of the features that the Media Library offers.

Just make the same tree structure as your Content-tree to group your Media Items and with the same permission set.